# Python Playwright doesn't work in my computer

Tags: python, playwright

Good afternoon! I have a very strange situation - the playwright library does not work for me. I run the script with an example from the documentation and nothing happens, the script does not complete. I tried adding print(), but it also doesn't output anything to the console. I wrote to my friend and sent my script - everything works for him. Please help me, I don't understand at all what the problem might be, because obviously there are no errors? The process does not complete and the console output remains in the same state as in the screenshot. Tell me, please, how can I try to fix this?

Playwright Version 1.42.0 |
Python 3.11.4 |
Windows 10

app.py:

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

with sync_playwright() as p:
 browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=False)
 page = browser.new_page()
 print(browser)
 print(page)
 page.goto("https://playwright.dev/")
 page.screenshot(path="example.png")
 browser.close()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3upwI.jpg)

I ran the script on a friend's computer and it works

Comment: Do you have a debugger on where it's stopping the code at a breakpoint? I suggest running it on PowerShell, without the IDE, so you can discern whether the issue is with the IDE or your OS/Python setup.

Comment: In you anaconda prompt: `pip install playwright; playwright install-deps; playwright install chrome`

Answer (score -1):

The solution that works for me is: open the registry editor, open the command processor and set an empty value for the variables, as shown in the figure.

[image]